# Chow group of a specific scheme related to the localization of the affine line at two points.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-k-theory

Given a scheme $X$, let $S=\varprojlim\limits_{U\subset X\times \mathbb{A}^1}U$ where $U$ is a Zariski open that contains both of $X\times\{1\}$ and $X\times\{0\}$. What does the Chow group $CH^i(S)$ look like? Is it $CH^i(X)\oplus CH^i(X)$?

Comment: you should explain what type of "limit" you are considering: Is $S$ a scheme?

Comment: @hm2020 Good point. $S$ is a scheme because it can be written as the inverse limit of schemes with affine transition maps. You can assume that $X$ is affine then $S$ is also affine. Now you can define $CH^i(S)$ as the Chow groups this scheme or as the direct limit of Chow groups of $U$'s. These two also should coincide.